# Find the last decimal digit of the number

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given the following exercise:
Find the last decimal digit of the number $7^{123}$.Do I have to find the modulo with $100$ ?

Comment: Mod $10$ is enough. Indeed mod $5$, since the number is clearly odd.

Comment: $7^4 \equiv 1\mbox{ mod }10$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $7^2\equiv-1\mod10$. Can you take it from here? :-)

Comment: So,the last digit of the number is $3$,right? :-)

Comment: Yes. $7^{123}=7\ ^{2\cdot61}\cdot7\equiv(-1)^{61}\cdot7\equiv-7\equiv3\mod10$.